# how to draw 'inhibitory' arrow in latex tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, graphs

i'm using this tikz-based library to draw nodes and arrows between them (https://github.com/jluttine/tikz-bayesnet). I want to draw an arrow that has a vertical line tip (`|`) (which usually means inhibition). How can this be done in tikz?

this is the code that draws a regular arrow from node "A" to node "B" that I want to replace with `|`:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Define nodes
  \node[const] (A) {$A$};
  \node[const, below=1cm of A] (B) {$B$};
  % connect them
  %%% how to make this an arrow with | tip?
  \edge{A}{B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

to compile you need the bayesnet package from the above link.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries. Also missing is the definition of the `const` style, so a composing a  a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) will help to flush out those details as well.

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so it can be compiled.

Comment: @cfr I updated the code to have MWE.

Comment: You don't need to download the library if you have e.g. TeX Live installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: custom arrow]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[const] (A) {$A$};
  \node[const, below=1cm of A] (B) {$B$};
  \edge [-Bar] {A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes! is there a way to make the arrow end a bit before (higher) than "B"?

Comment: Have you tried `shorten >=2pt` or whatever?

Comment: Oops, sorry for the quick  response, without deep thinking. I will delete it soon.

Comment: @Jesse No problem! Very easily done ;).